# Argument of type '"error"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EAlertType'

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm writing redux store with redux toolkit and I've run into a problem, I'm having Enum type in my code and when I try to assign a string to it for example 'error' it gives me this error.

```
Argument of type '"error"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EAlertType'.ts(2345)
```

## ENUM

```
export enum EAlertType {
  info = 'info',
  success = 'success',
  warning = 'warning',
  error = 'error',
  default = 'default',
}
export interface IAlert {
  msg: string,
  alertType: EAlertType,
  timeout: number,
  id: string,
}
```

My code

```
export const fetchPresentations = createAsyncThunk(
  GET_PRESENTS,
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/embed/');
      return res.data;
    } catch (err: any | AxiosError) {
      const { errors } = err?.response?.data;
      if (errors) {
        history.push('/bible');
        return errors.forEach((error: IError) => dispatch(alert(error?.msg, 'error')));
      }
    }
  },
);
```

I'm using react-toastify lib for toasts

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with this

```
export const fetchPresentations = createAsyncThunk(
  GET_PRESENTS,
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/embed/');
      return res.data;
    } catch (err: any | AxiosError) {
      const { errors } = err?.response?.data;
      if (errors) {
        history.push('/bible');
        const alertT = 'error' as EAlertType;
        return errors.forEach((error: IError) => dispatch(alert(error?.msg, alertT)));
      }
    }
  },
);
```